# Magento 2 : How to check product is in stock by color and size?

Tags: magento2, product, addtocart

I want product can be pre order if not in stock.
suppose, Product X has 3 sizes S,M and L.
and colors Red, Blue and Black.

At Product Details Page, If I select size L and Color black which is not in stock then, It should show 'Pre Order' instead of 'Add to Cart' Button.

Just like Magento's Back order process.

Comment: What does pre-order will do ? Same as add to cart or other behavior.

Comment: other process will remain same as add to cart. just I want is pre order product if not in stock, and product will get deliver when it will be available.

Comment: You have drop down or swatch ?

Comment: I have swatch. and I dont know how it renders on product details page.

Comment: Ah, If you have drop-down then I've solution for it. I am not sure about swatches you can check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/214867/49826
It will give you simple product id if it will work. then you can check with qty and change button texts with jquery.

Comment: @anonymous ohk. let me check. hope it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried this on a vanilla installation of Magento 2.3.3

I overrode the below js file.

`vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js`

**Steps:**

- Created a custom module.

Namespace : `Kcc`

Module Name : `Hello`

- `app/code/Kcc/Hello/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

  ```
  var config = {
  config: {
      mixins: {
          'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': {
              'Kcc_Hello/js/swatch-renderer-mixin': true
          }
      }
  }
  };
  ```
- `app/code/Kcc/Hello/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer-mixin.js`

```
    define(['jquery'], function ($) {
        'use strict';
```

`return function (SwatchRenderer) {
        $.widget('mage.SwatchRenderer', $['mage']['SwatchRenderer'], {
            _init: function () {
                console.log('getProductSwatchRenderer');
                this._super();
            },
            /**
             * Rewind options for controls
             *
             * @private
             */
            _Rewind: function (controls) {
                controls.find('div[option-id], option[option-id]').removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
                controls.find('div[option-empty], option[option-empty]').attr('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
                jQuery('#product-addtocart-button span').text('Add to Cart...'); // Modification one
            },

            /**
             * Rebuild container
             *
             * @private
             */
            _Rebuild: function () {
                var $widget = this,
                    controls = $widget.element.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeClass + '[attribute-id]'),
                    selected = controls.filter('[option-selected]');

                // Enable all options
                $widget._Rewind(controls);

                // done if nothing selected
                if (selected.length <= 0) {
                    return;
                }

                // Disable not available options
                controls.each(function () {
                    var $this = $(this),
                        id = $this.attr('attribute-id'),
                        products = $widget._CalcProducts(id);

                    if (selected.length === 1 && selected.first().attr('attribute-id') === id) {
                        return;
                    }

                    $this.find('[option-id]').each(function () {
                        var $element = $(this),
                            option = $element.attr('option-id');

                        if (!$widget.optionsMap.hasOwnProperty(id) || !$widget.optionsMap[id].hasOwnProperty(option) ||
                            $element.hasClass('selected') ||
                            $element.is(':selected')) {
                            return;
                        }

                        if (_.intersection(products, $widget.optionsMap[id][option].products).length <= 0) {
                            $element.attr('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
                            jQuery('#product-addtocart-button span').text('Backorder me'); // Modification two
                        }
                    });
                });
            },

        });
        return $['mage']['SwatchRenderer'];
    };});`

- Once the changes are done then, deploy the static contents.

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

**NOTE**: I have added two new lines in above js file. Check the lines in-front of the comments

`// Modification one` and `// Modification two`

As the `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` file is self explanatory by the comments, you can see that I have modified the add to cart button label when the options are not available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is very helpful

Comment: @DimplePanchal : Glad that it helped :) Check the browser compatibility as well.